# Using objects from instance with simulation / loop node and the Mesh Boolean node in geometry nodes 3.4.1 or 3.5 geometry-nodes-simulation

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

I’m trying to see if we can **incrementally use a Mesh Boolean node (with the Union option) on each instanced object** with the new simulation / loop node to **create better topology**.    (**Is there another way to incrementally loop through instanced objects in 3.4.1 and use a Mesh Boolean-Union node on each of them separately?**)

Link to branch I tried testing with:
https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/archive/blender-3.5.0-alpha+geometry-nodes-simulation.508fd044b44a-linux.x86_64-release.tar.xz

**Thought process:**

1. Get each object from instance
2. **Loop through each object from instance incrementally while doing a Mesh Boolean Union**. (**Is there another way to loop through instanced objects and use a Mesh Boolean-Union? is it possible in Blender 3.4.1 or is 3.5 my best bet?**)

I know we can use the **Remesh modifier** and the **Decimate modifier** but the geometry doesn't always look that great and it may require multiple steps to fix what it creates.

**Original objects:**
Notice the intersecting faces see arrows.  (Doing a Mesh Boolean – Union cleans this up but I need to do each object)

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

**Using Remesh Modifier** it creates a lot of geometry and “strange” face combinations.

[image: img3]

I then do a **Decimate**, it cleans things up a bit but still issues

[image: img4]

What I'm trying to do is almost have each object in the instance connected separately to the **Mesh Boolean Node using the Union option** (see below),  without having to make each connection individually (since the amount of objects in the instance will vary).

[image: img5a]

Nice geometry created with no internal faces either.

[image: img5]

I know separating each object on it's own and adding a Boolean Union to it should work but if you have dozens and dozens of objects and want to try several variations it becomes not viable.

See Blend file Below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around fix for intersecting faces and internal geometry, this may help someone else.

**(Left to Right)**

The **1st image** is the original image with overlapping faces / edges

**The Fixes:**

The **2nd image** uses the Mesh boolean node with Union.

The **3rd image** uses an "inverse mold node"

[image: img]

[image: img2]

[image]